# USB drive file access history

Tags: security, filesystems, usb

I recently forgot my USB drive at work and a collegue found it. I got the drive after 4 days. I have a feeling my colleague accesed or copied my personal files.

How can I find out?

Answer (score 0):

You have no means to know whether he copied the files or not,as such auditing can be enforced only with particular domain policies on machines where users have no privileges.

For example, you coworker could have unplugged the USB stick, and plug it on his personal computer. It worse, if he had Linux, just mounted the USB stick in read only to prevent timestamp changes.

Note that on windows you can do the same. To prevent thefts, you should encrypt the USB stick.